# UIActivityViewController view's bottom hidden after presenting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am presenting UIActivityViewController from my controller, the bottom of the UIActivityViewController is hidden. I have used following code

```
NSString * message = @"My too cool Son";
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_orange@3x.png"];
NSArray * shareItems = @[message, image];
UIActivityViewController * avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

when i use this in new project it works fine but not in myproject.

after opening mail my project's view controller also goes down and it is hidden(this is happening in all the views of the Project). Any one help me to find out the issue

Comment: If it doesn't work properly in your project that is likely because you are doing something wrong in your project that is causing it to display incorrectly.

Comment: Yes. there must be something wrong in my project. but not able to identify what it is. do you have any idea to find it?.

Comment: No, you'll have to give us more to go on - we can't see your project from here.

Comment: Finally I have fixed the issue. The window frame was set wrongly. Thanks for your reply @mattsven.